# What is regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following string

> sssHi this is the test for regular Expression,sr,Hi this is the test for regular Expression

I would like to replace only

> Hi this is the test for regular Expression

segment with some other string.

the first segment in string "sss **Hi this is the test for regular Expression**" should not be replaced

I wrote following regex for the same :

```
/([^.]Hi\sthis\sis\sthe\stest\sfor\sregular\sExpression)|(Hi\sthis\sis\sthe\stest\sfor\sregular\sExpression)$/
```

but it matches both segments. I want to match only the second one as first segement is prefixed by "sss".

```
[^.]
```

should match nothing except newline right? So group

```
  "([^.]anystring)"
```

should only match "anystring" that is not preceded by any chanrachter except newline. 
Am I correct?

any thoughts.

Comment: The . operator inside brackets does not mean the same thing as when it is outside. Inside the brackets it's a literal period (.)

Comment: use `\b`. e.g. `\b(Hi this is the test`...`)\b`

Comment: read `lookahead` and `lookbehind` assertion [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead)

Comment: @diEcho: Javascript does not support lookbehind

Comment: but `lookahead` can be useful

Comment: @BradChristie `\b` matches a "word boundary", whereas a "word" is defined as "consecutive sequence of word characters". Unfortunately, those are those matched by `\w` or `[0-9A-Za-z_]` only. You need to use `\s+` (white-space) instead (but not quite the same way).

Comment: @Bergi [There is no Javascript.](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix)

Comment: @PointedEars: Yes, that's true but still shorter to type. But: Does your matrix know any ES-based language that supports lookbehind regexes?

Comment: @Bergi And it's still misleading, so please don't use it. Sorry, no such implementation in the Matrix yet, and I don't think there is any. However, I have not yet excluded the possibility to add an implementation of lookbehind to [JSX:regexp.js](http://pointedears.de/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=JSX&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fregexp.js) which supports several PCRE features already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching a string that is *not* preceded by another string is a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) and not supported by JavaScript's regex engine. You can however do it using a callback.

Given

```
str = "sssHi this is the test for regular Expression,sr,Hi this is the test for regular Expression"
```

Use a callback to inspect the character preceding `str`:

```
str.replace(/(.)Hi this is the test for regular Expression$/g, function($0,$1){ return $1 == "s" ? $0 : $1 + "replacement"; })
// => "sssHi this is the test for regular Expression,sr,replacement"
```

The regex matches both strings so the callback function is invoked twice:

1. With

   - `$0 = "sHi this is the test for regular Expression"`
   - `$1 = "s"`
2. With

   - `$0 = ",Hi this is the test for regular Expression"`
   - `$1 = ","`

If `$1 == "s"` the match is replaced by `$0`, so it remains unchanged, otherwise it is replaced by `$1 + "replacement"`.

Another approach is to match the second string, i.e. the one you want to replace including the separator.

To match `str` preceded by a comma:

```
str.replace(/,Hi this is the test for regular Expression/g, ",replacement")
// => "sssHi this is the test for regular Expression,sr,replacement"
```

To match `str` preceded by any non-word character:

```
str.replace(/(\W)Hi this is the test for regular Expression/g, "$1replacement")
// => "sssHi this is the test for regular Expression,sr,replacement"
```

To match `str` at the end of line:

```
str.replace(/Hi this is the test for regular Expression$/g, "replacement")
// => "sssHi this is the test for regular Expression,sr,replacement"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
str.replace(/(.*)Hi this is the test for regular Expression/,"$1yourstring")
```

The **.*** is greedy, therefore matching the longest possible string, leaving the rest for the explicit string you wanted to match.